# Query Sub-Key From Athena Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have a table called test_raw in Athena that is mapped to this key:

```
s3://my-bucket/test/raw/events/successful/
```

Further, into this key, I have:

```
s3://my-bucket/test/raw/events/successful/123/log_0.json
s3://my-bucket/test/raw/events/successful/456/log_1.json
```

If I `select * from db_name.test_raw;` in response I get contents from both `123.log_0.json` and `456.log_0.json` as expected.

Ideally, I want to query for only contents in the 123 key without changing the table path to `s3://my-bucket/test/raw/events/successful/123/`.

Therefore, is it possible to do something like `select * from db_name.test_raw.123;`?

Comment: You're probably better off partitioning your data and then querying by partitions, e.g. /test/raw/events/successful/id=123/log.json, then `select * from db_name.test_raw where id='123'`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html

Comment: Got it I'll try this out. That said, can I partition by a filename i.e:
`/test/raw/events/successful/123_log.json` 
to
`/test/raw/events/successful/id=123/log.json`